# How to recover .git/objects/pack/ files?

Tags: git, gitlab

Hello I accidentally delete my .git/objects/pack/ files . How can I recover that one? Whenever I git pull or do the command on git it shows ---- error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever pushed your repository to a git server, or has it only been stored on your computer?

Comment: @duskwuff I delete on a git server.

Answer (score 2):

Clone your repository in a new folder.

```
git clone <your repository url> new-folder
```

Delete your current .git folder.

Then copy new-folder/.git to your current folder.

Comment: can u explain me a little more detail ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you push your project to Github/Bitbucket ... before? If you did that, you just need to clone it from Github/Bitbucket and copy .git folder.

Answer (score 0):

A git pull means you have a remote repository.

A lest, check what a new `git clone` would get you: clone your remote repository in a new local folder, and start working from there.
That new repo would have its proper `.git/objects/pack`.

You can then add the files from your current working tree to that new local clone.